# Using 64-bit intrinsics in OMNeT++

Tags: omnet++, intrinsics

I'm using OMNeT++ 5.0 and I would like to have access to the Intel intrinsic capabilities on my cpu. I'd prefer to use the 64-bit versions instead of the 32-bit versions. An example:

int i = _popcnt64(15);

I've been reading some posts from a couple years ago (2013) that indicate that OMNeT++ packages executables in 32-bit regardless. I configured OMNeT++ to not use clang and was able to make _popcnt32() work.

I would like someone to verify that OMNeT++ does still package everything in 32-bit and that it is the reason the 64-bit intrinsics won't work. However, if anyone knows of a workaround to allow for use of 64-bit intrinsics, I would appreciate any help with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMNeT++ 5.0 on macOS and Linux supports 64-bit compilation. On Windows, OMNeT++ 5.0 came with a 32-bit compiler. On the other hand, OMNeT++ 5.1 on Windows is bundled with a 64-bit compiler (gcc from the mingw-w64 project). In fact 32-bit compilation is no longer supported on OMNeT++ 5.1 and later.

Comment: Using 5.1 worked perfectly. Quick other question: do you know when the final release of 5.1 will be? Or a rough timeframe?

Comment: We are still waiting for Eclipse 4.6.3 release (23rd of March) as it contains several important fixes for the CDT (C++ component). So the release will be around the beginning of April. Still, the current RC version is feature complete so you can start using it now without worrying to much.

Comment: Great. Thank you!